# How to load Jquery DataTable on dynamically created rows from ajax response?

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatable, dynamic-columns

I am loading jQuery Datatable on document ready function and I am creating table body rows from ajax response but datatable still showing data not available and not doing any sorting and counting on rows added in the table from ajax response.

```
<table id="mytable">                   
  <thead>                   
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tableBody"></tbody>
</table>
```

```js
function getUsers(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "/user.php",
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(json) {               
      var tr; 
      for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) { 
        tr = $('<tr/>');
        tr.append("<td><a>" + json[i].first_name + ' ' + json[i].last_name + "</a></td>");
        tr.append("<td><a href='mailto:" + json[i].email + "'>" + json[i].email + "</a></td>"); 
        $("#mytable > tbody").append(tr);                    
      }
    },
  });
}   

$(document).ready(function() {
  getUsers();
  $('#mytable').dataTable();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this function

```
function getUsers(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "/user.php",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {
            var tr;
            for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
                tr = '<tr>';
                tr+="<td><a>"+json[i].first_name +' '+json[i].last_name+"</a></td>";
                tr+="<td><a href='mailto:"+ json[i].email +"'>"+ json[i].email + "</a></td>";
                tr+='</tr>';
               $("#tableBody").append(tr);
            }

        },
    });
}
```

I thing it will work for you.

Comment: Yes I have tried this, but it ain't worked. So I write this it in a separate method i.e. the dynamiclly created rows and then I called in ajax success. And below that I called  $('#mytable').dataTable(); and it worked.

Comment: I just missed to put this ` $("#tableBody").append(tr);` inside the for loop